# Issues in installing r-base-dev

Tags: r, dependencies, ubuntu-12.04, apt

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit .I was trying to install R as specified on this [link](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/installing-r.html) . I am successfully able to install r-base but getting errors when trying to install r-base-dev . Here is the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: gfortran but it is not installable
              Depends: libblas-dev but it is not installable or
                       libatlas-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: liblapack-dev but it is not installable or
                       libatlas-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libreadline-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libjpeg-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libpng-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libbz2-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: cdbs but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have added the security key as stated in that link as well as the following line  `deb http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/`  to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

I have also added the following ppa : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter` .

Any help would be appreciable.

PS: I was also doubtful with my lists in /var/lib/apt/lists so I deleted and created it again. Still having the same error .

Comment: Do you have all those packages it says are unmet dependencies? You need those `-dev` packages to be able to compile the fortran and c code in the `-dev` package of `R`.

Comment: No i do not have those packages. I searched for them but I am not able to install those packages those. Error it showing is :          `Package gfortran is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
`

Comment: I have also searched via synaptic package manager which broken packages i have but no broken packages are listed in that too.

Comment: Try to install each one separately.  `sudo aptitude search` first.  you might have to update the names accordingly.  `gfortran` for instance should install via: `sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.6`.

Comment: Thanks for help but I have tried doing so and still I am getting the same error .I installed gfortran 4.8 and other such but the error is still the same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made sure that the restricted and universe repositories are enabled (which was disabled in case of mine ). For doing this , Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>F2</kbd> type software-properties-gtk and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Under `Ubuntu Software` tab enable all the repositories.
[image]
After which run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Again run

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

And done successfully.

I got the above solution from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)