# Can't install r-base on Ubuntu 19.10; unmet dependencies r-recommended

Tags: r, ubuntu, dependencies

In general, I am new in working with Ubuntu (19.10;eoan) and currently trying to install r-base. r-base-dev is installed.
When I do so, I get the following message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.2-1xenial) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have used the following Threads to try to fix my problem - without any succes.

[Installing r-base; Depenency: r-recommended missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086958/installing-r-base-depenency-r-recommended-missing)

[Issues in installing r-base-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631191/issues-in-installing-r-base-dev)

For this one I stopped at the section: "Disable/Remove/Purge PPA:". Because I was not able to understand the process.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

I will appreciate any solution or advice to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what you actually tried (and the order) it is difficult to try and pinpoint why it doesn't work, but I recently installed this on 19.10 myself. I used the following.

```
# Get the key from the keyserver.
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

# Add the repository to your sources.list. Make sure that it does not already exist
# and that it is not a typo in there. Making a backup of the file before running the
# next line is useful.
echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

# Install base, dev and other dependencies.
sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev r-cran-curl r-cran-openssl r-cran-xml2 libssl-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

It worked without any problem for me. It is very important that you add the correct repository to your `sources.list`. Judging by the error message you are using a repository referring to Ubuntu Xenial and not Ubuntu Eoan.

Comment: The first two commands worked normaly. 'sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev r-cran-curl r-cran-openssl r-cran-xml2 libssl-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev' came up with more dependencies. I tried to solve the problem with the 'atitute' packages and it worked just fine. I am not able to explain what happened, but it workerd.